# SMTP Google rewrite my mail origin

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I want send a simple mail that goes from anyone mail to a list of mails. The SMTP already send my mail to the destiny, the problem it's that in the mail recibered appear the origin mail changed.

```
private function mandarMail($personaMailTo, $personasCC, $idScoring){
        //Pillamos los datos enteros del scrogin
        $configGmail = array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'mymail@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'mypass',
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset' => 'utf-8',
            'newline' => "\r\n"
        );    

        //cargamos la configuración para enviar con gmail
        $this->email->initialize($configGmail);

        $this->email->from('noreply@promovil.es'); //can be the mail of a comercial or user of my platform
        $this->email->to("roberburnday@gmail.com");
        $this->email->subject('Test me estoy cagando en todo');
        $this->email->message(
            $this->load->view('template/emailScorCom',$data = NULL,true)
        );
        $this->email->send();
        //con esto podemos ver el resultado
        var_dump($this->email->print_debugger());

    }
```

Should be appear "`noreply@promovil.es`" but appear "mymail@gmail.com". How can solve it? It's a problem of google SMTP or the bug it's into my code?

Comment: Gmail does not let you set the `from` address unless that address is one you have verified as one you own. Other SMTP providers may permit it, but you should note that it'll **very often** be blocked as spam because of SPF records. Better to use a `Reply-To` header.

Comment: this isn't a problem, it's a CRM closed and there are only 20 persons at the equip (i can notificate it to them)